# How to find compilation preprocessor used in Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, macros, preprocessor

Is there a way to find out the preprocessor in c++ code, e.g. NDebug, NOMAXMIN, etc?

I can do something like

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::cout << "in debug mode";
#else
    std::cout << "in release mode";
#endif
```

but there are so many preprocessors and colleagues can also define their own.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio to write C++ code, not gcc.

Comment: Do you mean all the preprocessor directives?  There is a list of standard ones and many compiler vendors provide their own also.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to produce a list of all defined macros? A *macro* is a named piece of code such as `_DEBUG`, a *preprocessor* is a software tool that evaluates macros (among other things).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines)

Comment: @spectras thanks reminder, i'm actually working on microsoft visual studio.

Comment: @athos> in that case the full list is available in visual studio [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Comment: @spectras That's the vs built-in preprocessors . How to figure them out so that c++ code is aware of the settings? Even better, could c++ code be aware of the programmer defined preprocessors?

Comment: @athos> I don't understand. You have the full list of predefined macros, with exact meaning of each in case you need them in your code. What exactly do you miss?

Comment: How to handle a new preprocessor defined by a colleague?

Comment: @athos> by asking that colleague what the meaning of the macro he defined is? We don't do mind reading. Neither do compilers.

Comment: I'm looking for an automatic solution

Comment: An automatic solution to what? Extracting the meaning of a macro from a colleague's mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio automatically defines `_DEBUG`, so I suggest you use that.

However, for a portable solution, use `NDEBUG`, like this:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
  // nondebug
#else
  // debug code
#endif
```

---

References:

1. [Predefined Macros Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)
2. [Automatic #defines according to Debug/Release config in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604283/automatic-defines-according-to-debug-release-config-in-visual-studio-2010)
3. [C / C++ : Portable way to detect debug / release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249282/c-c-portable-way-to-detect-debug-release)

---

PS: There is no automatic way of detecting the meaning of a *custom* Macro defined by a colleague, since the colleague might do almost anything.

Comment: I'm not targeting _Debug only but all preprocessors

Comment: @athos I updated my answer, do you like it now? I liked your question, thus upvoted!